# wxStaticBitmap is not reflecting parent back ground gradiation with style wxTRANSPARENT_WINDOW instead of that its showing parent back groung colour

Tags: c++, visual-c++, wxwidgets

I have created a panel then in paint event i am doing gradiation , On top of panel i am creating wxstaticbitmap with style wxTRANSPARENT_WINDOW ,but background of staticbitmap showing parent backgroung colour instead of gradient colour , could someone please help me out of this ,Here is my code

NOTE: i am using png type images

Code:

```
MWpanel::MWpanel()
{
wxbitmap bitmapPNG
wxStaticBitmap *bit = new wxStaticBitmap(this ,-1 ,bitmapPNG ,wxDefaultPosition ,wxDefaultSize ,wxTRANSPARENT_WINDOW)

}
MWpanel::OnPaint(wxPaintEvent &event)
{
wxColour col1
wxColour col2
wxBufferedPaintDC dc(this);
dc.GradientFillLinear(wxRect(0, 0, this->GetSize().GetWidth(), this->GetSize().GetHeight()), col1, col2, wxSOUTH);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [SetBackgroundStyle(wxBG_STYLE_TRANSPARENT)](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#af14f8fd2ed2d30a9bbb5d4f9fd6594ec) and not `wxTRANSPARENT_WINDOW`. See the "erase" sample included in wxWidgets for some example code.